# how to select a node from xml

Tags: xml, winforms

in this context  i am loading an xml document then selecting node using its name and repositioning the node....but in the below code its showing the error 
"'//Textbox[@Name='PlayerID_txt'' has an invalid token."

```
XmlDocument nodeDoc = new XmlDocument();
            nodeDoc.Load(@"E:\Projects\Niyas\CompressorAndDecompressor\Reports\Reports\Reports\rdlcReport\PlayerSubReport1.rdlc");



            string itemId="";
            XmlNode node=null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++ )
            {

                if (dgvDesigngrid.Rows[i].Cells["Textbox_Id"].Value != null && dgvDesigngrid.Rows[i].Cells["Textbox_Id"].Value !="")
                {
                    itemId = dgvDesigngrid.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();



                     node = nodeDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Textbox[@Name='{0}'", itemId));
                }



               // XmlNode node = nodeDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/root/node[@Textbox_Id = '{0}']", itemId));
                if (node != null)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.AppendChild(node);
                }
            }
        }


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="ReportsReportsDatasets">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>ae389da4-d5e0-4a2e-9a16-8b35e854428e</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="SubReportDetails">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="PlayerID">
          <DataField>PlayerID</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="PlayerName">
          <DataField>PlayerName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="BelongsTo">
          <DataField>BelongsTo</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>ReportsReportsDatasets</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName>Reports.Reports.Datasets</rd:DataSetName>
        <rd:TableName>PlayerMasterDetailsDataTable</rd:TableName>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType>Reports.Reports.Datasets.Dataset+PlayerMasterDetailsDataTable, Reports.Datasets.Dataset.Designer.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</rd:ObjectDataSourceType>
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>0.98425in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>0.98425in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>0.98425in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.23622in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Player ID</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Player Name</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox5">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>Belongs To</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox5</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.23622in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="PlayerID_txt">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!PlayerID.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                    <rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="PlayerName_txt">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!PlayerName.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="BelongsTo_txt">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!BelongsTo.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember />
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Details" />
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>SubReportDetails</DataSetName>
        <Top>3.0607cm</Top>
        <Left>1.89653cm</Left>
        <Height>1.2cm</Height>
        <Width>7.5cm</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>4.21875in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>2cm</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>2cm</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>2cm</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>2cm</BottomMargin>
    <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <rd:ReportID>75d0c901-26e2-4b62-9761-479cea86626e</rd:ReportID>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
</Report>
```

Comment: Your xml file schema might be helpful for finding a problem

Answer (score 1):

`node = nodeDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Textbox[@Name='{0}'", itemId));`

I think it's missing a closing `]`